# scrapy and selenium seem to intervene each other

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I don't have much experience in web scraping or using scrapy and selenium. Apologize first if there are too many bad practices in my code.

Brief background for my code: I tried to scrape information of products from multiple websites using scrapy, and I also use selenium because I need to click the "view more" button and "No thanks" button on the web page. Since there are href for different categories on the website, I also need to request those "sublinks" to make sure I don't miss any items not shown on the root page.

The problem is, I notice in this for loop `for l in product_links:`, scrapy and selenium seems to act strangely. For example, I would expect `response.url == self.driver.current_url` would always be true. However, they become different in the middle of this for loop. Furthermore, `self.driver` seem to capture some elements not existing in the current url in `products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-url]')` and then fail to retrieve them again in `sub = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[(@class="shelf-container") and (.//div/@data-url="' + l + '")]//h2')`

Many thanks. I'm really confused.

```
from webScrape.items import ProductItem
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from selenium import webdriver

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'name'
    domain = 'https://uk.burberry.com'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to driver')
        self.start_urls = [self.domain + '/' + k for k in ('womens-clothing', 'womens-bags', 'womens-scarves',
                                        'womens-accessories', 'womens-shoes', 'make-up', 'womens-fragrances')]
        self.pool = set()

    def parse(self, response):
        sub_links = response.xpath('//h2[starts-with(@class, "shelf1-section-title")]/a/@href').extract()
        if len(sub_links) > 0:
            for l in sub_links:
                yield Request(self.domain + l, callback = self.parse)
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        email_reg = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="dc-reset dc-actions-btn js-data-capture-newsletter-block-cancel"]')
        if email_reg.is_displayed():
            email_reg.click()
        # Make sure to click all the "load more" buttons
        load_more_buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="load-assets-button js-load-assets-button ga-shelf-load-assets-button"]')
        for button in load_more_buttons:
            if button.is_displayed():
                button.click()
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-url]')
        product_links = [item.get_attribute('data-url') for item in products if item.get_attribute('data-url').split('-')[-1][1:] not in self.pool]
        for l in product_links:
            sub = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[(@class="shelf-container") and (.//div/@data-url="' + l + '")]//h2')
            if len(sub) > 0:
                sub_category = ', '.join(set([s.get_attribute('data-ga-shelf-title') for s in sub]))
            else:
                sub_category = ''
            yield Request(self.domain + l, callback = self.parse_product, meta = {'sub_category': sub_category})

    def parse_product(self, response):
        item = ProductItem()
        item['id'] = response.url.split('-')[-1][1:]
        item['sub_category'] = response.meta['sub_category']
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-title transaction-title ta-transaction-title"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        self.pool.add(item['id'])
        yield item
        others = response.xpath('//input[@data-url]/@data-url').extract()
        for l in others:
            if l.split('-')[-1][1:] not in self.pool:
                yield Request(self.domain + l, callback = self.parse_product, meta = response.meta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy is an asynchronous framework. The code in your `parse*()` methods does not always run linearly. Wherever there is a `yield` there, the execution of that method may stop there for some time while other parts of the code run.

Because there is a `yield` in the loop, that explains why you are experiencing that unexpected behavior. At `yield`, some other code of your program resumes execution and may switch the Selenium driver to a different URL, and when the code resumes the loop the URL from the Selenium driver has changed.

To be honest, you don’t really need Selenium in Scrapy for your use case, as far as I can see. In Scrapy, things like Splash or Selenium are only used on very specific scenarios, for things like avoiding bot detection.

It is usually a better approach to figure out the structure of the page HTML and the parameters used in requests by using the developer tools from your web browser (Inspect, Network) and then reproducing them in Scrapy.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! The main reason I use selenium is because I need to click the "view more" buttons. If I don't click those buttons, I won't be able to get all the products (I tried the same xpath twice, before and after I click the button and the results are different). Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Yes. The common Scrapy approach is to open the Network tab of the devtools of your browser, see what the View More button actually does (it most likely sends an AJAX request), and reproduce that in your spider.

Comment: In this case, the click triggers a request to https://uk.burberry.com/womens-new-arrivals-new-in/?start=2&pageSize=40&productsOffset=&cellsOffset=0&cellsLimit=&__lang=en and you could simply perform requests to such an URL directly, changing the parameters as needed. If you get an unexpected response, you might need to ensure you also send the required headers and cookies, for which, again, the browser developer tools are your friends.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gallaecio. I manage to do that without selenium and it is very efficient and painless. Grateful!

Comment: Hi Gallaecio, hope you wouldn't mind me circling back to this post. I recently found that my code still can't completely capture everything probably due to the asynchronous framework. For example, I have seen exception like '+' between str and Nontype happening when I do `self.domain + l`. I believe as you described, the code might resume and the variable `l` has changed (somehow to NoneType Object, strangely). Is there any way I can avoid this kind of issue? I guess my program design is poor and would love to hear what you think. Thanks a lot.